# ActiveMQ log is full of messages like "Could not set property excludedDestinations"

Tags: logging, configuration, activemq-classic

Example of message from file "activemq.log":

```
2019-02-13 11:46:40,390 | INFO  | localhost bridge to Unknown stopped | org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport | ActiveMQ BrokerService[localhost] Task-173925
2019-02-13 11:46:40,468 | ERROR | Could not set property excludedDestinations on org.apache.activemq.network.NetworkBridgeConfiguration@73188b2b | org.apache.activemq.util.IntrospectionSupport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///10.27.120.91:52657@61616
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert from class java.lang.String to interface java.util.List with value []
    at org.apache.activemq.util.IntrospectionSupport.convert(IntrospectionSupport.java:219)[activemq-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.util.IntrospectionSupport.setProperty(IntrospectionSupport.java:178)[activemq-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.util.IntrospectionSupport.setProperties(IntrospectionSupport.java:110)[activemq-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.processBrokerInfo(TransportConnection.java:1360)[activemq-broker-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.command.BrokerInfo.visit(BrokerInfo.java:126)[activemq-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.service(TransportConnection.java:338)[activemq-broker-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$1.onCommand(TransportConnection.java:188)[activemq-broker-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.onCommand(MutexTransport.java:50)[activemq-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.onCommand(WireFormatNegotiator.java:113)[activemq-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.onCommand(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:300)[activemq-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.doConsume(TransportSupport.java:83)[activemq-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:214)[activemq-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:196)[activemq-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_101]
2019-02-13 11:46:40,468 | ERROR | Could not set property staticallyIncludedDestinations on org.apache.activemq.network.NetworkBridgeConfiguration@73188b2b | org.apache.activemq.util.IntrospectionSupport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///10.27.120.91:52657@61616
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert from class java.lang.String to interface java.util.List with value []
    at org.apache.activemq.util.IntrospectionSupport.convert(IntrospectionSupport.java:219)[activemq-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.util.IntrospectionSupport.setProperty(IntrospectionSupport.java:178)[activemq-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.util.IntrospectionSupport.setProperties(IntrospectionSupport.java:110)[activemq-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.processBrokerInfo(TransportConnection.java:1360)[activemq-broker-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.command.BrokerInfo.visit(BrokerInfo.java:126)[activemq-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.service(TransportConnection.java:338)[activemq-broker-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$1.onCommand(TransportConnection.java:188)[activemq-broker-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.onCommand(MutexTransport.java:50)[activemq-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.onCommand(WireFormatNegotiator.java:113)[activemq-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.onCommand(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:300)[activemq-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.doConsume(TransportSupport.java:83)[activemq-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:214)[activemq-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:196)[activemq-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_101]
2019-02-13 11:46:40,484 | ERROR | Could not set property dynamicallyIncludedDestinations on org.apache.activemq.network.NetworkBridgeConfiguration@73188b2b | org.apache.activemq.util.IntrospectionSupport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///10.27.120.91:52657@61616
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert from class java.lang.String to interface java.util.List with value []
    at org.apache.activemq.util.IntrospectionSupport.convert(IntrospectionSupport.java:219)[activemq-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.util.IntrospectionSupport.setProperty(IntrospectionSupport.java:178)[activemq-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.util.IntrospectionSupport.setProperties(IntrospectionSupport.java:110)[activemq-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.processBrokerInfo(TransportConnection.java:1360)[activemq-broker-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.command.BrokerInfo.visit(BrokerInfo.java:126)[activemq-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.service(TransportConnection.java:338)[activemq-broker-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$1.onCommand(TransportConnection.java:188)[activemq-broker-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.onCommand(MutexTransport.java:50)[activemq-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.onCommand(WireFormatNegotiator.java:113)[activemq-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.onCommand(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:300)[activemq-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.doConsume(TransportSupport.java:83)[activemq-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:214)[activemq-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:196)[activemq-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_101]
```

The message is fired 2-3 times every second. "activemq.xml" does not contain section <networkConnectors>. So ActiveMQ should use some default (correct?) values.

What is going wrong?

Comment: Can you share the configuration file?

Comment: Here [activemq.xml](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=70554715864052223098).

Comment: The error message doesn't jive with the configuration file. Have you tried with the latest 5.15.x release?